# Adwords script - exclude TODAY from date range

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, date-range

I am trying to create a Google Adwords script that can somehow exclude TODAY's date from the Date Range.

According to [Adwords documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_keywordselector) the general syntax is as follows:
`forDateRange("20130324", "20130324")`

The only supported values are as follows:
`TODAY, YESTERDAY, LAST_7_DAYS, THIS_WEEK_SUN_TODAY, LAST_WEEK, LAST_14_DAYS, LAST_30_DAYS, LAST_BUSINESS_WEEK, LAST_WEEK_SUN_SAT, THIS_MONTH, LAST_MONTH, ALL_TIME`

However I need to be able to exclude **TODAY** from this range.

Any ideas on the code I would need to write to be able to produce this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Script, you need to change the start_date?

If you could explain a bit better as you will use these date ranges in your script, you may become clearer

For exclude Today you can use "Yesterday" in end_date, but to produce yesterday in yyyymmdd you can use this function to return the date as you wish.

```js
 function format_date(date){
  var date = date;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
  var dd  = date.getDate().toString();
  var mmChars = mm.split('');
  var ddChars = dd.split('');
  var datestring = yyyy + (mmChars[1]?mm:"0"+mmChars[0]) + (ddChars[1]?dd:"0"+ddChars[0]);
  return datestring;
} 
  
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  yesterday = format_date(date);
  Logger.log(yesterday);
```

Now you can use  forDateRange("20130324", yesterday) in you script, for all days, you will have a date range until today.

I hope it helped you